# No rows fetching but need a value

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, group-by

I need some help with the following query.

```
Select date, Source,count(*) as TOTALCOUNT
from Table A
where date = '2014-10-15' and Source = 'EMAIL'
group by date,source
```

There is no `EMAIL` `source` for a particular day. So, it gives no rows. 
But I want to get `0` in `Totalcount` even if `EMAIL` is not there for that day but can present next day.

It should be like,

```
Date,Source, Totalcount
15/10/14,Email,0
```

I used `ISNULL` function not working as no rows has been resulted.

Answer (score 1):

You could perform a join with a "constant" query. It's an ugly hack, but it should do the trick:

```
SELECT    c.date, c.source, COALESCE(totalcount, 0)
FROM      (SELECT '2014-10-15' AS date, 'EMAIL' AS source) c
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   date, source, COUNT(*) AS totalcount
           FROM     a
           GROUP BY date, source) a 
       ON a.date = c.date AND a.source = c.source
```

Comment: Almost there, I think you need an `ISNULL(,)` around `totalcount`

Comment: @Sev09 yup, kind of missed the mark here :-( I went with `coalesce` which is more ANSI-friendly, but in principal you are correct.

Comment: The asker would be better off using a table with all dates in case there was no data on a certain date (I realize there was in this case). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125504/how-can-i-generate-a-temporary-table-filled-with-dates-in-sql-server-2000