# Open Ticket Count Per Day

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks like this

```
id | Submit_Date | Close_Date
------------------------------
 1 | 2015-02-01  | 2015-02-05
 2 | 2015-02-02  | 2015-02-04
 3 | 2015-02-03  | 2015-02-05
 4 | 2015-02-04  | 2015-02-06
 5 | 2015-02-05  | 2015-02-07
 6 | 2015-02-06  | 2015-02-07
 7 | 2015-02-07  | 2015-02-08
```

I can get a count of how many ticket were open on a particular day with this:

```
Select count(*) from tickets where '2015-02-05' BETWEEN Submit_Date and Close_Date
```

This gives me `4`, but I need this count for each day of a month. I don't want to have to write 30 queries to handle this. Is there a way to capture broken down by multiple days?

Comment: you could build a loop that does this in probably < 10 loc. don't think you can do it in a single select without 30 subqueries which kind of defeats the point.

Comment: Hmm... I guess I could, I just seems like there should be a way to handle this in a single query.

Comment: I can only think of Stored Procedure. Or use Excel to populate 30 lines.

Comment: @TZHX I did the loop, but it gave me 30 different result sets instead of putting them in a single result set.

Comment: yes... use a temp table or something along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

I created a solution a way back using a mix of @Heinzi s solution with the trick from [Generate a resultset of incrementing dates in TSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478951/generate-a-resultset-of-incrementing-dates-in-tsql)

```
declare @dt datetime, @dtEnd datetime
set @dt = getdate()
set @dtEnd = dateadd(day, 100, @dt)

SELECT dates.myDate,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) 
      FROM tickets 
     WHERE myDate BETWEEN Submit_Date and Close_Date
   )
FROM 
(select Dates_To_Checkselect dateadd(day, number, @dt) mydate
from 
    (select distinct number from master.dbo.spt_values
     where name is null
    ) n
where dateadd(day, number, @dt) < @dtEnd) dates
```

Code is combined from memory, I don't have it in front of me so there can be some typo's

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need a table that contains each date you want to check. You can use a temporary table for that. Let's assume that this table is called `Dates_To_Check` and has a field `myDate`:

```
SELECT myDate,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM tickets 
         WHERE myDate BETWEEN Submit_Date and Close_Date)
  FROM Dates_To_Check
```

Alternatively, you can [create a huge table containing every possible date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6125504/87698) and use a WHERE clause to restrict the dates to those you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in SQL Server 2012 or newer you can do this using window functions with a small trick where you add 1 to the open days -1 to the closing days and then do a running total of this amount:

```
select distinct date, sum(opencnt) over (order by date) from (
  select 
    Submit_Date as date, 
    1 as opencnt 
  from 
    ticket

  union all

  select 
    dateadd(day, 1, Close_Date), 
    -1
  from 
    ticket  
) TMP
```

There's a dateadd + 1 day to include the close date amount to that day

Answer (score 0):

You could generate the list of dates and then retrieve the count for each date in your dateset.

The cte part generates the date list since the beginning of the year (an ssumption) and the next part calculates the count from your data set.

```
with cte as
    (select cast('2015-01-01' as date) dt // you should change this part to the correct start date
    union all
    select dateadd(DD,1,dt) dt from cte
    where dt<getdate()
    )
    select count(*)
    from tickets
    inner join cte
    on cte.dt between Submit_Date and Close_Date
    group by cte.dt
```