# SQL determine averages based on open and closed dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an oder table (in MySQL DB) that lists the open and closed date and time for orders.  For order that are open the closed date and time is blank.

Here is an example of the table:

```
Order   OPEN                    CLOSED  
1       2002-06-17 18:37:27     2002-07-05 16:37:27
2       2003-05-16 18:37:27     2003-06-28 16:37:27
3       2004-06-15 18:37:27     2004-07-23 16:37:27
4       2003-07-14 18:37:27     2003-07-18 16:37:27
5       2002-08-13 18:37:27     2002-09-27 16:37:27
6       2004-09-12 18:37:27     2005-07-19 16:37:27
7       2005-10-11 18:37:27     2006-07-18 16:37:27
8       2006-11-10 18:37:27     2006-12-06 16:37:27
9       2007-12-11 18:37:27     2008-07-04 16:37:27
10      2009-01-12 18:37:27     
11      2015-02-13 18:37:27     2015-07-17 16:37:27
```

I would like to create a query that would tell me by day the number of orders that I have open.  I then want to average the number open each day of the month so that I can look at the month or month trend of open orders.

I know that I could query for any day and determine the number of open orders, so I could create a program that would do this for each days and then insert the daily totals into a database that I could then average.

I would like to know if there is a pure SQL solution to this.  Is there a way with the table above to write a query that the results would be the average number of open orders by month?

Comment: include what your tried so far??

Comment: Yes there is: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

To get the daily orders:

`SELECT COUNT(*), DATE(open) FROM orders WHERE close IS NULL GROUP BY DATE(open)`

Comment: That doesnt solve the OP issue. Because orders doesnt close until the close date. Other days is open.

Answer (score 1):

First you need a days table so you could do a `left join`

Using select [**Generate days from date range**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157282/generate-days-from-date-range)

This use store procedure in [**MSQL**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125504/how-can-i-generate-a-temporary-table-filled-with-dates-in-sql-server-2000)

---

Then you do something  like this

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8b4ba0/17)

> I have to modify your sample data to one month because I only create one month days table.

```
select day_id, count(order_id) total_open
from 
(
    select *
    from  
        days d left join
        orders o 
            on  d.day_value >= date(o.o_open)
            and (
                   o.o_close is null -- still open
                or d.day_value <= o.o_close
            )
    order by day_id
) as open_byday
group by day_id
```

This consider an order open for day **D** if you close the order that day. I mean was open that day for a while before you close it.

Otherwise you have to change to `or d.day_value < o.o_close`