# How can I cross join the following query results with a table of dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am looking for a query which gives me the daily playing time. The start (first_date) and end date(last_update) are given as shown in the Table. The following query gives me the sum of playing time on given date. How can I extend it to get a table from first day to last day and plot the query data in it and show 0 on dates when no game is played.

```
SELECT startTime, SUM(duration) as sum
FROM myTable
WHERE startTime = endTime
GROUP BY startTime
```

[image]

Comment: Your query would not appear to do what you claim.

Comment: I edited my question, is it more clear now?

Answer (score 2):

To show date when no one play you will need create a table `days` with a `date` field `day` so you could do a `left join`. (100 years is only 36500 rows).

Using select [**Generate days from date range**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157282/generate-days-from-date-range)

This use store procedure in [**MSQL**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125504/how-can-i-generate-a-temporary-table-filled-with-dates-in-sql-server-2000)

I will assume if a play pass the midnight a new record begin. So I could simplify my code and remove the time from `datetime` field

```
SELECT d.day, SUM(duration) as sum
FROM 
    days d
    left join myTable m
         on CONVERT(date, m.starttime) = d.day
GROUP BY d.day
```

Comment: I am new to sql server, can you please complete the query for me?

Comment: what part? What about my assumption if a game pass midnight how is that record created?

Comment: Unfortunately, the midnight is not marked. so if a game starts at 11pm then it might finish at 1am. Day have to be manually calculated. Part) getting the day table in your query

Comment: And what part you need help? Can you prepare a small [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5c2bd/3) with your data for me? And I try to write the query you need later this day

Comment: Can you please check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32228349/how-to-make-time-per-day-from-variable-segments-of-tracktime-in-sql-server

Comment: What should I check there? Will you post the sqlFiddle?

Comment: Using [Generate days from date range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157282/generate-days-from-date-range) you could just use the subquery rather than making a separate table. Though, that would slightly negatively would impact performance, and it would make the query more complicated.

Comment: @Jakar I just give him the options. But you are right creating the table is the best performance. And I said 35000 rows in a table is just pennies.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you could try:

```
SELECT SUM(duration) AS duration, date
FROM myTable
WHERE date <= 20140430 
    AND date => 20140401
GROUP BY date
```

This would get the total time played for each date between april 1 and april 30
As far as showing `0` for dates not in the table, I don't know.

Also, the table you posted doesn't show a `duration` column, but the query you posted does, so I went ahead and used it.

Comment: Picture updated. Yes, but I want to display all the dates and 0 for dates on which no game is played.